# value doesn't change when I'm trying to toggling the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code, when im trying to toggle the checkbox (I can view the changes in inspect), the value of the checkbox doesnt change

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
<input type="checkbox"  name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1" value="">
      <label>
       Facility is far
      </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1" value=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: checkbox uses the attribute "checked" as you can see here :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp not value

Answer (score 3):

checkout with value

```
 if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
          $("h2 span").text(checkBoxval);
     }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkBox = $("[type='checkbox']");
  var checkBoxval = $checkBox.val();
  $("h2 span").text(checkBoxval);
  $checkBox.on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $("h2").show();
      $("h2 span").text(checkBoxval);
    } else {
      $("h2").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
  <input type="checkbox" name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1" value="My Checkbox value" checked="true">
  <label>
       Facility is far
      </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1" value="" />
  <h2>Your value is <span></span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can't see you js code but, you SHOULDN'T duplicate an id attribute like you did with NCONF_RSN1

Comment: This is more a "comment" than an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

You given the same id to both input element, give two different id. Then it will work

Comment: How can you know it will work for sure, without hes js code?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my problem, added "_" on hidden id

Instead of id="NCONF_RSN1" i used id="NCONF_RSN1_".

i just tried it, i dont know how it worked.

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
<input type="checkbox"  name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1" value="">
      <label>
       Facility is far
      </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="NCONF_RSN1" id="NCONF_RSN1_" value=""/>
</div>
```